# Template inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

I have made a template singleton class, I have also made a data structure that is templated.

My question is; how do I make my templated data structure inherit from a singleton so you can only have one float type of this structure?

I have tested both seperate and have found no problems.
Code provided under... (That is the problem)

```
template <class Type>
class AbstractRManagers : public Singleton<AbstractRManagers<Type> >
```

The problem is the code above doesn't work I get alot of errors. I cant get it to no matter what I do template a templated singleton class...
I was asking for maybe advice or maybe if the code above is incorrect guidence?

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

template <class Type>
class Singleton
{
    public:
        virtual ~Singleton();
        Singleton();
        static Type* m_instance;
};
template <class Type>
Type* Singleton<Type>::m_instance = 0;

#include "Singleton.cpp"
#endif

#ifndef SINGLETON_CPP
#define SINGLETON_CPP
#include "Singleton.h"

template <class Type>
Singleton<Type>::Singleton()
{
}

template <class Type>
Singleton<Type>::~Singleton()
{
}

template <class Type>
Type* Singleton<Type>::getInstance()
{
    if(m_instance==nullptr)
    {
        m_instance = new Type;
    }
    return m_instance;
}

#endif


#ifndef ABSTRACTRMANAGERS_H
#define ABSTRACTRMANAGERS_H

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include "Singleton.h"

template <class Type>
class AbstractRManagers : public Singleton<AbstractRManagers<Type> >
{
    public:
        virtual ~AbstractRManagers();

        int insert(Type* type, std::string name);
        Type* remove(int i);
        Type* remove(std::string name);
        Type* get(int i);
        Type* getS(std::string name);
        int get(std::string name);
        int get(Type* i);
        bool check(std::string name);
        int resourceSize();
    protected:

    private:
        std::vector<Type*> m_resources;
        std::map<std::string,int> m_map;
        std::stack<int> m_freePos;
};
#include "AbstractRManagers.cpp"

#endif

#ifndef ABSTRACTRMANAGERS_CPP
#define  ABSTRACTRMANAGERS_CPP

#include "AbstractRManagers.h"
template <class Type>
int AbstractRManagers<Type>::insert(Type* type, std::string name)
{
    int i=0;
    if(!check(name))
    {
        if(m_freePos.empty())
        {
            m_resources.push_back(type);
            i = m_resources.size()-1;
            m_map[name] = i;
        }
        else
        {
            i = m_freePos.top();
            m_freePos.pop();
            m_resources[i] = type;
            m_map[name] = i;
        }
    }
    else
        i = -1;

    return i;
}
template <class Type>
int AbstractRManagers<Type>::resourceSize()
{
    return m_resources.size();
}
template <class Type>
bool AbstractRManagers<Type>::check(std::string name)
{
    std::map<std::string,int>::iterator it;

    it = m_map.find(name);

    if(it==m_map.end())
        return false;

    return true;
}

template <class Type>
Type* AbstractRManagers<Type>::remove(std::string name)
{


    Type* temp = m_resources[m_map[name]];
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {
        std::map<std::string,int>::iterator it;
        it = m_map[name];
        m_resources[m_map[name]] = NULL;
        m_freePos.push(m_map[name]);
        delete (*it).second;
        delete (*it).first; 

        return temp;
    }
    return NULL;
}

template <class Type>
Type* AbstractRManagers<Type>::remove(int i)
{
    if((i < m_resources.size())&&(i > 0))
    {
        Type* temp = m_resources[i];
        m_resources[i] = NULL;
        m_freePos.push(i);
        std::map<std::string,int>::iterator it;
        for(it=m_map.begin();it!=m_map.end();it++)
        {
            if((*it).second == i)
            {
                delete (*it).second;
                delete (*it).first; 
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
    return NULL;
}
template <class Type>
int AbstractRManagers<Type>::get(Type* i)
{
    for(int i2=0;i2<m_resources.size();i2++)
    {
        if(i == m_resources[i2])
        {
            return i2;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
template <class Type>
Type* AbstractRManagers<Type>::get(int i)
{
    if((i < m_resources.size())&&(i >= 0))
    {
        return m_resources[i];
    }
    return NULL;
}
template <class Type>
Type* AbstractRManagers<Type>::getS(std::string name)
{
    return m_resources[m_map[name]];
}
template <class Type>
int AbstractRManagers<Type>::get(std::string name)
{
    return m_map[name];
}
template <class Type>
AbstractRManagers<Type>::~AbstractRManagers()
{
}

#endif



#include "AbstractRManagers.h"
struct b
{
    float x;
};
int main()
{
    b* a = new b();
    AbstractRManagers<b>::getInstance()->insert(a,"a");


    return 0;
}
```

This program produces next errors when compiled :

```
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &,const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stack(166) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(124) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(71) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(451) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Pr=std::less<std::string>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,int>>,
1>              _Mfl=false
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(520) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_nod<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,int,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,int>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(659) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_val<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,int,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,int>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(81) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,int,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,int>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\chris\desktop\311\ideas\idea1\idea1\abstractrmanagers.h(28) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\chris\desktop\311\ideas\idea1\idea1\abstractrmanagers.h(30) : see reference to class template instantiation 'AbstractRManagers<Type>' being compiled
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &,const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stack(166) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &,const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stack(166) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::deque<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::deque<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::deque<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\deque(1725) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::deque<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::deque<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::deque<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\deque(1725) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::deque<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::deque<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::deque<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\deque(1725) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(1502) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(1502) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(1502) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(2582) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(2582) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(2582) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1356) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1356) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1356) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1179) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1179) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1179) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(318) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(318) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(318) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2676: binary '<' : 'const std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Other than the singleton and the abstract managers, what's the problem?

Comment: Readjusted question so it might help.

Comment: @ChrisCondy Martinho was actually pointing out that using a singleton is seen as an anti-pattern in almost all situations and having a class called `SomethingManager` is similarly a sign that your design could be improved.

Comment: You need to post more code; at a minimum your singleton definition. You also need to tell us what errors you are getting.

Comment: Very well you will most likely regret it =s...

Comment: Problem solved missing a #include <string.h>
crazy errors to get for something like that...

Comment: Surely you mean `#include <string>`? Also, you still have the problem of having a `Singleton` in your system (c:

Comment: Yes i meant #include <string>. No singletons are required by the unit, so therefore I have to use them. And they are extremely recommended for us, for now =)

Comment: Tell them you'll stop paying your fees if they keep recommending Singleton.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'd avoid singleton all together.

Having said that, take a look into [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). That is how you should implement it.

---

Errors in your code :

1. `no 'Type* Singleton<Type>::getInstance()' member function declared in class 'Singleton<Type>'`
2. `error: 'std::string' has not been declared`

You need to declare `static Type* getInstance();` in your singleton, and include  somewhere.

Comment: Why avoid singletons? They are a useful pattern IMHO.

Comment: @EdHeal They are considered an anti-pattern. They make testing difficult, dependencies implicit, they make every client object know the implementation details (you access them differently to any other kind of object in your system), even if nobody else cares, they remove the need for design, are easily understood as a concept by novices, but difficult to comprehend in their bug-iness even by wizards.

Comment: @PeterWood - They just have there place for being pragmatic. I try to avoid them but somethings they are a useful compromise in certain circumstances.

Comment: @EdHeal The only use (I'd call it a misuse) of a singleton is that is it a wrapper for a global variable. Nothing else.

Comment: @EdHeal: I think since 1998, which is the year I began software development, I never used just one instance of singletons. If I really need just one instance of something, then know what, I create just one instance. Prominent example: `std::cout`. This has the nice side effect of avoiding all the problems of singletons, with the added bonus of providing some future exensibility. Example: "We'll always just need a single database connection". Reality bites two years later: "We'll need a connection to replication databases for read only purposes, or we must stop growing..."

Comment: The one place that we used it was to have a global configuration for the system (that comprised of many applications). It was used to ensure that multiple configurations (some parts where dynamic, others static) were not used in error as lots of developers were involved in the project that was developed by a large number of developers, in many countries and the system was modified for the particular mission involved. Seemed rather pragmatic.

Comment: @EdHeal Having all parts of such a large system have access to all the configuration really isn't a good idea. Firstly, it's unnecessary. A subsystem should only have explicit access to the configuration it needs. Secondly, if the configuration is dynamic you make it possible for any part of the system to erroneously screw up an unrelated part. Thirdly, and I'm stretching myself now, it sounds as though this configuration was used in many systems, even those that didn't use all of it, so you have redundancy. Configuration which isn't used is confusing, inefficient, and not simple. KISS (c:

Comment: The software was generic and the synamic part was for the *hot switch* in the event of failure. Yes - there was redundancy but it helps to get the overall status of the system. As for KISS - One place to get the configuration instead of having to figure out where to look.

Comment: @EdHeal The same would be accomplished with using a global variable, or event better, some kind of inversion of control.

Comment: @VJovic - The singleton object hide the internals of parsing the configuration values, providing the *hot switch* and logging other objects that are interested in changes to any of the dynamic values. It just provided an environment for people that wrote modules that attach to the generic system could rely on. (BTW - The team that wrote the generic system are different from those that needed to add additional functionality for the mission in question)

Comment: @EdHeal It also makes classes that use it untestable (or very difficult to unit test).

Comment: @VJovic - Sometimes makes it difficult - but the classes only use a subset of those configuration values. The *hot switch* feature was extremely hard to test, but that is integration testing. I had many long (and usually sleepless) nights over that one.

Comment: @EdHeal LOL and you still think it is good? Have you even tried to use some kind of inversion of control? :)

Comment: @VJovic - I guess at the end of the day we have to agree to disagree. I just think that pragmatic is sometimes the better option.